# Variadic template that determines the best conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, variadic-templates, c++14, overload-resolution

How can we implement a variadic template that, given a type `T` and a list of types `E`<sub>1</sub>, `E`<sub>2</sub>, ... `E`<sub>N</sub>, determines the type of that list for which the conversion from `T` to that type is, according to overload resolution, the best?

`void` should be the output if no best conversion exists - in other words, when either there is an ambiguity or `T` cannot be converted to any type in the list. 
Note that this implies that **our template should be SFINAE-friendly, i.e. not hard-error when no best conversion exists.**

The following `static_assert`s should succeed:

```
static_assert( std::is_same< best<int, long, short>,       void >{}, "" );
static_assert( std::is_same< best<int, long, std::string>, long >{}, "" );
static_assert( std::is_same< best<int>,                    void >{}, "" );
```

<sub>(Assuming, for simplicity, that `best` is an alias template referring to the actual template)</sub>

This case is left unspecified:

```
static_assert( std::is_same< best<int, int, int>, ???>{}, "" );
```

Either `void` or `int` should be acceptable here. (If the latter is chosen then we can still check in a wrapper template whether the result type is contained twice in the list, and if it is, output `void` instead).

Answer (score 6):

My currently best approach:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> using eval = typename T::type;

template <class T> struct identity {using type = T;};

template <typename T, typename... E>
class best_conversion
{
    template <typename...> struct overloads {};

    template <typename U, typename... Rest>
    struct overloads<U, Rest...> :
        overloads<Rest...>
    {
        using overloads<Rest...>::call;

        static identity<U> call(U);
    };

    template <typename U>
    struct overloads<U>
    {
        static identity<U> call(U);
    };

    template <typename... E_>
    static identity<eval<decltype(overloads<E_...>::call(std::declval<T>()))>>
    best_conv(int);

    template <typename...>
    static identity<void> best_conv(...);

public:

    using type = eval<decltype(best_conv<E...>(0))>;
};

template <typename... T>
using best_conversion_t = eval<best_conversion<T...>>;
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33cdf56bc966c882). For the "unspecified" case above this template will give you `int`.

The basic idea is to put a bunch of overloaded functions with one parameter into different scopes that name lookup will look in, with the parameter and return type of each overload corresponding to one of the types in our list. 
`overloads` does this job by recursively introducing one declaration of `call` at a time and adapting all previously introduced `call`s from the base specializations via `using` declarations. That way all `call`s are in different scopes but are considered equally when it comes to overload resolution.

Then apply SFINAE in a function template `best_conv` to check whether the call to `call` (inside  `overloads`) is well-formed: If it is, take the return type (which is by definition the parameter type) of the selected declaration and use it as our result - it will be the type we are looking for.
 Also provide a second overload of `best_conv` that returns `void` and can be selected as a default (when SFINAE applies in the first overload and kicks it out of the candidate set).

The return types use `identity<>` to avoid type decays when working with e.g. array or function pointer types.

Comment: `(...)` is a bit iffy: many types it is UB to pass as.  Make it `T&&,...` and drop it?

Comment: @Yakk It is merely intended to take an `int` (to make it a worse match if both overloads of `best_conv` stay in the candidate set), which is fine. I can make it `long` if you want.

Comment: Ag, I see: not `declval<U>()`.  The design I had in my head had tye `void` case competing with the other overloads more directly (with a `...` to guarantee it went last), and I projected it onto your different solutuon.  Sorry!